# Equally distribute operators with single parallelism in a multi-parallel Flink application

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We have a flink application that has a map operator at the start. The output stream of this operation is routed to multiple window functions using filters. The window functions all have a parallelism of 1. We form a union of the output of the window functions and pass it to another map function and then send it to a sink.

We need the parallelism of both the map functions to take the parallelism of the environment. This happens as expected and the parallelism of the window function does turn out to be 1.
We have set 1 slot per task manager.

The issue is that all the window function tasks end up going to only the 1st task manager when we set the parallelism of the environment to greater than 1. The events end up going to this task manager alone and end up causing a bottleneck. Is there a way to distribute the window function task across multiple task managers when we have parallelism > 1? Will doing a `rebalance()` help?

Comment: Does each Task Manager have a single slot? From the description above, it sounds like you have multiple slots per TM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If each task manager has only one slot, and all of the window function tasks are in the same task manager, then apparently all of the window function tasks are in the same slot.

That being the case, you could use [slot sharing groups](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/#task-chaining-and-resource-groups) to force different windows into different slots, and thus onto different task managers.

Comment: thanks for the reply. Will this apply across task managers? i.e. Will this ensure that the different window functions are spread across slots in all task managers? Also, when I take a union of the outputs of the window functions, what happens to the tasks of the map function that follows the window functions? In the documentation, it says the group name is inherited.

Comment: I you only have one slot per TM, then forcing each window into its own slot will force them onto different TMs. I think you'll want to put that map function that follows the windows into the default slot sharing group.

Comment: You can use the Flink WebUI to see what the resulting execution graph looks like. Or use `System.out.print(env.getExecutionPlan())` to print it out.

Comment: Thanks, @david anderson.

Answer (score 1):

With Flink 1.9.2/1.10.0 or later, you can set the `cluster.evenly-spread-out-slots` config boolean to `true`.

Side note - instead of using a filter on multiple streams to create a router, use a `ProcessFunction` with multiple side outputs, one per target window operator. This is more efficient, as you're not replicating the data N times and then filtering down to a subset.